# c# wpf only 1 file gets selected

Tags: c#, wpf, file, file-io

I created a WPF app in which I want to select many files from any given directory. The problem is that whenever I try to select multiple files, it will just copy the first file exactly as many times as many files I selected, instead of giving me all the different files.

What am I doing wrong?

```cs
TextFile textFile = new TextFile();
string[] arrAllFiles;

private void btnOpenFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;

    OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
    choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
   
    choofdlog.Multiselect = true;
    
    if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() ==true)
    {
        //string sFileName = choofdlog.FileName;
        
        arrAllFiles = choofdlog.FileNames; //used when Multiselect = true           
    }
    
    //add all files in textbox
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arrAllFiles.Length; i++)
    {       
        textFile.files.Add(choofdlog);
        myStream = textFile.files[i].OpenFile();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream);
        textFile.readFile.Add(reader);
        lbFiles.Items.Add(arrAllFiles[i]);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i only use c# occasionally, so i can't give you a syntactical guarantee, but what i see at first glance is this

```
textFile.files.Add(choofdlog);
```

should be

```
textFile.files.Add(arrAllFiles[i]);
```

or

```
textFile.files.Add(choofdlog[i]);
```